# geom_raster showing inverted colors

Tags: raster, r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a simple single band raster in R using ggplot. The only problem with my plot is that the colors are inverted. How can I fix that?

```
### For plotting I am using ggplot2 and ggpspatial packages 
## Map 4.13
# Convert the Band 5 raster to a dataframe in string format
B5 = raster("~B5.TIF")

B5_df = as.data.frame(B5, xy = T)
names(B5_df)[3] = "Values"
# Values represents Band 5 column values in the data-frame
ggplot() + 
  layer_spatial(points, aes(col = value)) +
  geom_raster(data = B5_df, aes(x = x, y = y, alpha = Values)) +
  annotation_scale(location = "bl") +
  annotation_north_arrow(location = "tr", which_north= "true") +
  labs(title = paste("Map 4.13")) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

My plot
[image]

Actual Plot
[image]

The raster can be downloaded from [here](https://app.box.com/s/251dfqcq9kz8iiyq9j79d5dv384gbi60)

Comment: If you provide a way to download the data within your script (make it reproducible) someone may be able to assist.

Comment: @coconn41, I have added a link to download the raster as suggested.

Comment: What package contains the `layer_spatial()` call? In fact, you should list all of the packages you have loaded in your script. EDIT I see it now in your commented out lines. For best practice, you should list them directly in the code as `library(ggplot2)`, `library(raster)` and `library(ggspatial)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the colored points that show up in the map, as they don't have a data source, I will address your inverted colors problem (and some other issues):

What you are looking for is the code below:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(ggspatial)
library(ggplot2)
#Given that the file you gave me is saved to your desktop
setwd("~/Desktop")
B5 = raster("~/Desktop/LT52240632011210CUB01_B5.TIF")

B5_df = as.data.frame(B5, xy = T)
names(B5_df)[3] = "Values"

ggplot()+
  geom_raster(data=B5_df,aes(x,y,fill=Values))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'black',high = 'white')+ 
  annotation_north_arrow(location='tr',which_north='true')+ 
  labs(title="Map 4.13")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Your problem arose within the `aes` call. You used the `alpha` argument, which, in a general sense, `alpha` is transparency, not color. Changing the `alpha` argument to the `fill` argument fixes that by assigning a color to each cell value instead of a transparency.

When using the `fill` argument, you then have to set a color palette. This way R knows that you want to go from white to black or vice versa. This is done in the `scale_fill_gradient` call. Your data is a bit strange in that you want the lower values to be darker, and the higher values to be lighter, but it isn't unheard of.

Another issue you are running in to is that your data has no coordinate reference system. This is why it throws the warning of:

```
Warning message:
In f(...) : True north is not meaningful without coord_sf()
```

Technically speaking, the program doesn't know what north is. I'm not sure what your data is exactly, but perhaps you can do some digging and find what coordinate reference system it is in, and then set the coordinate reference system.

A small final point: You don't need `paste("Map 4.13")` within `labs(title = )`, you can just set the `title` argument equal to your desired text, as shown in the code above.

Comment: Where is library ggspatial found?